# check your network connection or proxy settings

Tags: visual-studio

I can't sign in visual studio 2017 i got this message "we could not download a license. please check your network connection or proxy settings".
I tried sign in whith my account so i got a message 
"we could not refresh the credentials for the account operation returned an invalid status code 'forbidden'"
I tried also download again visual studio but its not help,
and also i opend a new account and its also not help.

Answer (score 1):

Every effort gone in vain except following method worked like a miracle:

1. Sign up at [signup.live.com](https://signup.live.com)
2. Choose `Get a new email address`
3. After creating an outlook mail, simply click `sign in` button Visual Studio.
4. Use these same generated credentials and it will work

Still not sure why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after doing a fresh install on of windows 10 to my laptop. It turned out the problem was due the install of VS2017 not going smoothly. Re-running the installer and selecting to repair the installation fixed the issue.

If you're interested in the specific details of why it failed, read on...

The problem was actually caused by how win 10 installations work. After the initial install, it needed a reset to install some updates, this was all fine. After that reboot a few minutes later, I assume I was all set and started installing the tools I need. However after a few minutes it informed me it needed to upgrade the entire version of windows 10 and this would take about 90 minutes.

If I'd allowed it to do this then, I don't think I would have had the problem. However I was at work so decided to take the hit over lunch and in the meantime started setting up the other tools I needed, including vs2017. After the VS2017 installation completed it stated it needed to reboot to complete.

This reboot however also triggered the win 10 update. When it finally completed, it left me with a broken vs2017 installation.